# Why is this circuit component on without a potential difference?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

From the following graph, determine whether (h) will be on or off:
[image: graph]

I think (h) should be off because there is no potential difference across it. Is this correct?

**Edit:**

[image: graph 2]

Using the method provided by sweber, I should have (d) be on, yet the answer says it is off because there is no current flowing across (d).

Is the answer wrong or am I not getting the method right?

Comment: What are the circles with X's in them? That's the typical symbol for a mixer. Are those supposed to be mixers? Note also that homework-like questions *require* than you show what you have tried to solve the problem before the question can be considered valid for this site. Those are the rules we have to prevent a flood of people trying to get us to do their homework.

Comment: No, it is an absolute standard symbol for a bulb in electronics. A similar symbol exists for a mixer, but it has three terminals with arrows, does not make sense here, and is used more for sketches of signal flow, not the actual electronic schematic.

Comment: This symbol represents bulb. No this is not for my homework. I have no homework indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There IS a potential, and all three bulbs will be on.

First, you need a reference point to measure voltages. Let's take the wire right of the right battery, and define its potential as 0V.

If both batteries generate a voltage of 5V, the wire between the batteries will have a potential of 5V, and the wire left of the batteries will have 10V:

[image]

So, bulb 1 and 2 will both encounter a voltage of 5V, while bulb 3 encounters 10V. If the bulbs are identical (and are all made for 10V), bulbs 1 and 2 will be much dimmer than bulb 3.

Another fact: Bulb 1 and 2 act as voltage divider, so even if you remove the vertical blue wire, both horizontal wires will still have a potential of 5V. As result, there will be no current flow through the vertical blue wire. May be, this causes your confusion.

Finally, your circuit is equivalent to this one:

[image]

Again, you can remove the horizontal blue wire, as there will flow no current through it.

Comment: Nice use of colors.

Comment: How did you know that a circle with a cross in it is a bulb?

Comment: @DanielSank: because it's the standard symbol for a bulb, just as the long, thin and short, thick lines stand for a battery.  It's only strange that the terminals were arranged in a 90°-angle, not straight, at it's usual.

Comment: @sweber This is funny: in eight years of research I guess I've never used a light bulb in a circuit diagram :) In RF design the circle with a cross is a mixer.

Comment: May be. However, I have never considered static DC circuits as RF...

Comment: Could you please explain why there is no current flowing in blue wire?

Comment: I have edited my question. I tried to use the method presented here but failed, could you take a look at what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Bulb H is connected to second battery directly. As long as this bulb is not short circuited, there will be some applied potential difference across its terminals and hence it will be ON

Comment: As long as resistance of bulb 3 is not zero - otherwise the two voltage sources end up back to back (with a "short")